# Select using WHERE if any exist, else don't use WHERE

Tags: sql, hql

I want to select from a table where column = 'n'. If the result has 0 rows, I want to remove that conditional.

Some pseudo-sql might be:

```sql
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE COL_A = 1 AND COL_B = 'mystring'
ELSE
    SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE
    WHERE COL_A = 1;
```

I will only be using the first row in either result, so it would also be acceptable to somehow sort the result such that rows where `COL_B = 'mystring'` appear at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have too many values for each `col_a` value, you can use:

```
select t.*
from t
where col_a = 1
order by (case when col_b = 'mystring' then 1 else 2 end);
```

Just use the first row in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is MSSQL:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    MY_TABLE
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT
        COUNT(*) c
    FROM
        MY_TABLE
    WHERE
        COL_A = 1
    AND
        COL_B = 'mystring'
) MY_WHERE_COUNT
WHERE (
    MY_WHERE_COUNT.c > 0 AND MY_TABLE.COL_A = 1 AND MY_TABLE.COL_B = 'mystring'
)
OR (
    MY_WHERE_COUNT.c = 0 AND MY_TABLE.COL_A = 1
)
```